# nextauth callbacks dosen't seems to run

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, callback, next-auth

So I'm trying to set authentication with nextauth on my next.js app.
My callbacks from the GoogleProvider doesn't seems to run. If I add a console log I can not see it on console. And also if I change the return to false it doesn't seems to change anything,
thats my code on pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbacks: {
        async signIn({ account, profile }) {
          console.log('a comment'); // comment dossent print
          return true; // still working with return false
        },
      },
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

What am I missing?

```js
callbacks: {
  async signIn({ account, profile }) {
    console.log("a comment"); // comment dossent print
    return true; // still working with return false
  },
}
```

I want to use this callback function and can't seem to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake on assigning the callback block under the providers block. I think it should be outside of providers block. See the docs link below.

```
const authOptions = {
  providers: [...],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ account, profile }) {
      if (account.provider === "google") {
        return profile.email_verified && profile.email.endsWith("@example.com")
      }
      return true // Do different verification for other providers that don't have `email_verified`
    },
  }
  ...
}
```

See the docs here, https://next-auth.js.org/providers/google#example